# Python - read table with empty fields from file

Tags: python, parsing

In python, how can i parse table with empty fields?

For example, I want to print list of children names from this table (I get this as a txt file)

```
NAME CHILDREN_NAME   PHONE
A    A1              11
     A2              22
     A3              
B    B1              
     B2              33
C    C1              44
     C2
```

The problem is I have blank fields in the table and i dont know how can I split the table to chuncks so the right childrenname will refer to the right name

The result should be

```
"A" children names: A1, A2, A3
"B" children names: B1, B2
"C" children names: C1, C2
```

i tried to use split() or convert it to csv file but it doesn't help
any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.

Comment: please add some code what you did?

Comment: That said, you also have to clarify your problem.  On any give input line, how do you know which field is the name, which is the children name, and which is the phone?  Is it by character position?  Number of fields?  Format of the name?

Comment: well, the best way is to make it a csv file and then read it as I think of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using csv and regex, you can achieve the following result:

```
import csv
import re
with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    thelist = list(reader)
print [re.split('\s+', line[0])[1] for line in thelist][1:] # the CHILDREN_NAME column
```

Output:

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2']
```

[UPDATE] The following approach can meet your 2nd requirement:

```
import csv
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    thelist = list(reader)
result = OrderedDict()
parsed = [(re.split('\s+', line[0]))[:2] for line in thelist][1:]
for x, y in parsed:
    if x:
        temp = x
        result[x] = y
    else:
        result[temp] = ','.join([result[temp], y])
print result.items()
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'A1,A2,A3'), ('B', 'B1,B2'), ('C', 'C1,C2')]
```

Comment: Thanku! can you help me with how I reffer each children to it's parent? 
I mean, not just printing the second column, printing something like 
A: A1,A2,A3
B: B1,B2
C:C1,C2